# Почему не работает метод POST при fetch запросе?

Tags: reactjs, post, fetch

Пишу приложение на React и выходит ошибка:

> POST http://localhost:3000/api/petpage 400 (Bad Request).

Проверяю весь путь и все должно работать. Прикладываю код.

```
app.use('/api/petpage', apiPetRouter);
```

```
const [currentPets, setCurrentPets] = useState(ferms);
  const submitHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(event.target));
    if (data.pet_name?.trim().length && data.description?.trim().length && data.url?.trim().length ) {

      const response = await fetch('/api/petpage', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        },
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      });
      if (response.ok) {
        event.target.reset();
        const ferm = await response.json();
        setCurrentPets((prev) => [...prev, ferm]);
      } else
      {
        console.log('что-то пошло не так ...')
      }
    }
  };
```

apiRouter:

```
apiPetRouter.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const { pet_name, description, url } = req.body;
    console.log('itis req.body===>', req.body)
  const userId = req.session.user.id
  if (!pet_name || !description || !url) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: 'заполни все поля' });
    res.redirect('/petpage');
    return;
  }
  try {
    const ferm = await Ferm.create({
        pet_name,
        description,
        url,
        userId
    }
    );  

    res.status(201).json(ferm);
  } catch (error)  {
    console.log('ошибка при записи в БД', error)
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
  });
```

форма:

```
export default function PetForm({ submitHandler}) {
  return (
    <div className="row mt-3">
      <div className="col">
        <form action='' method="POST" onSubmit={submitHandler} 
>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1" className="form-label">Name of pet</label>
            <input 
              name="pet_name"
              type="text"
              // value={ferm.pet_name}
              className="form-control"
              id="exampleFormControlInput1"
              placeholder="Doddy kitty"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1" className="form-label">Description</label>
            <input
              name="description"
              type="text" 
              // value={ferm.description}
              className="form-control"
              id="exampleFormControlInput1"
              placeholder="tape text here.."
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1" className="form-label">Url</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="url"
              // value={ferm.url}
              className="form-control"
              id="exampleFormControlInput1"
              placeholder="www..."
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit"  className="btn btn-warning">ok</button>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Первый логичный вопрос — а почему вы решили, что сервер в принципе готов принимать то, что вы пытаетесь ему отправить? Второй логичный вопрос — что написано в теле присылаемого сервером ответа?

Comment: Вы отправляете `POST` запрос на `api/petpage`, а в вопросе привели код только `GET api/`. Приведите код `apiPetRouter`-а. Вероятно вы какие-то данные не передаете, из-за чего получаете `400` ошибку.

Comment: У вас кстати опечатка: `headers: { }, 'Content-Type': 'application/json',` у вас получается `headers` пустой, без `Content-Type`.

Comment: Да, вы правы. опечатку - поправил. Ручку в тему не ту вставил - отредактировал. в форму так же добавил путь action='/petpage/addpet' , error - POST../api/petpage 400 последний консоль лог доступный при дебагинге это перед строкой с fetch запросом с фронта. данные приходят, но не уходят на сервер

Comment: Ну так всё-таки что написано в теле присылаемого сервером ответа?

Comment: А где тело запроса парсится?

Comment: консоль браузера: PetPage.jsx:13 
 POST http://localhost:3000/api/petpage 500 (Internal Server Error)
_callee$ @ PetPage.jsx:13
tryCatch @ PetPage.jsx:2
eval @ PetPage.jsx:2
eval @ PetPage.jsx:2
asyncGeneratorStep @ PetPage.jsx:2
_next @ PetPage.jsx:2
eval @ PetPage.jsx:2
eval @ PetPage.jsx:2
submitHandler @ PetPage.jsx:8
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbac

Comment: это response (браузер): Internal Server Error

Comment: Заголовки : Request URL:
http://localhost:3000/api/petpage
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:
[::1]:3000
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Length:
21
Content-Type:
text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:
Thu, 07 Sep 2023 20:48:23 GMT
Etag:
W/"15-/6VXivhc2MKdLfIkLcUE47K6aH0"

Comment: То есть у вас 400 уже превратилось в 500? Ну а что в консоли сервера тогда?

Comment: в коде на сервере пытаюсь посмотреть консольлог, но на ручке (ни перед ни после) ничего не выходит

Comment: То есть сервер решил отвечать 500 просто без какой-либо причины и без каких-либо ошибок, что ли?

Comment: То есть у вас 400 уже превратилось в 500? Ну а что в консоли сервера тогда? – 
andreymal
 - - так и есть. после исправления опечатков (headers) были пустые. ошибка стала 500

Comment: Поправил по комментам выше, добавил путь на action в форму, перезагрузил webpack и немного продвинулся. теперь response 200, но упал react-dom : > assessment-2-raccoons-2023-msk@1.0.0 dev
> babel-node src/server.js

App has started on port 3000
GET /petpage 200 52.005 ms - 3710
itis req.body===> {
  pet_name: 'Teddy',
  description: 'Пес',
  url: 'https://kipmu.ru/wp-content/uploads/rcbljk.jpg'
}
POST /api/petpage 201 215.714 ms - 194     --- спасибо за свежий взгляд на проблему. дальше сам распутаюсь!